# Creating a js statement from array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Total Noob. Trying to expand some code to be more flexible. I've managed to get the "pieces" of the statement I need into an array. But now I want to make the statement run and I don't know how to take the pieces and make a statement that is evaluated.

```html
<div class="qvinsert" data-qvid="PQHxsX" data-app-ref="app1"></div>
```

```js
var app1 = qlik.openApp('fe96772a-caa7-442d-a77f-ed68764942ec', config);

$(".qvinsert").each(function() {
  var viz = {
    v: $(this).data("qvid"),
    a: $(this).data("appRef")
  };
  console.log(viz); //{v: "PQHxsX", a: "app1"}
  app1.getObject(this, "PQHxsX") //the line I'd like to create. If I write it out like this it works.
```

Tried all kinds of things like `[viz.a].getObject(this,[viz.v])`, but I feel like I'm just stabbing in the dark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stabbing in the dark is indeed not the way to program!

You're not too far off actually. `[viz.v]` has some extraneous brackets (you've created a single-element array here) — just `viz.v` is already the string you want for that function argument.

Transforming the string `"app1"` (i.e. the value of `viz.a`) into an actual reference to `app1` takes a little extra work, but is made easier by the fact that all globals exist as properties of the `window` object, and you can access said properties using array-like syntax.

So, again, though just surrounding the variable in array-literal brackets isn't useful, ironically it's not far off the solution:

```
window[viz.a].getObject(this, viz.v);
```

This should do the trick.

If `app1` is *not* a global, however — and we cannot really tell from your question — then you should look at putting it inside an object that can be indexed by name in the same way:

```
var apps = {
   "app1": qlik.openApp('fe96772a-caa7-442d-a77f-ed68764942ec', config)
   // can add more possibilities here!
};
```

Then it's `apps[viz.a].getObject(this, viz.v);`. This would, in honesty, be tidier anyway.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Being new, the surrounding comments help me understand
Unfortunately I got an error trying the first solution because it does not appear to be in the window. 
`window[viz.a] //undefined`

It may help to point out that all of the code above is inside a require funciton
`require( ["js/qlik"], function ( qlik ) {
     var app1 = qlik.openApp('fe96772a-caa7-442d-a77f-ed68764942ec', config);

    $(".qvinsert").each(function() {
 var qvid = $(this).data("qvid");
 app1.getObject(this,qvid);
 });
});`

Comment: I tried your second (tidier) suggestion and placed the apps in an object that can be indexed.
... that did the trick for me. I need to do a little more learning on variable scopes.

Comment: Yep. All good. Have fun!